# Multiple Image Upload and Rename - avoiding multiupload image field

Tags: nodes, media

I'm looking to provide the following functionality on my Drupal site:

I'd like to make an easy to use content type that allows users to upload multiple photos easily. The uploader needs to allow them to dump in files, rename them and upload them. I'm currently using the multiupload image field which I've found to do the job of uploading well but, I don't like the thought of increasing my php upload limit to allow users to upload a whole load of photos at once. I wondered whether there was an uploader that allows users to drop in their photos and, providing an individual photo isn't over the upload limit, will handle the upload of all of the photos?

An added bonus would be the ability to rename photos, once they've been uploaded.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Plupload has a variety of upload widgets that should allow you to upload without increasing the php limit. [You can view examples of the widgets here.](http://www.plupload.com/examples/) You can pick one of the [modules that integrate pulpload on its project page at https://www.drupal.org/project/plupload.

Comment: Also, [This patch to the Media module](https://www.drupal.org/node/2074625) should allow you to rename files after upload.